# In Photoshop how to get transformation of a SmartObject by script?

Tags: photoshop, transformation, layer

This is just a plain problem as it is asked. I need to export the transformation information of SmartObjects. But a layer doesn't seem to have such properties.

Comment: Can you not rasterize the layer for export purposes?

Comment: I don't need the image, the transformation only.

Comment: I end up switched to parsing PSD file myself. Currently all is fine.

Comment: could you please be more specific and explain what you did? I need the same thing and some help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Dairo That would be a long article. Tons of things inside a PSD are undocumented, and I've guessed a lot to find out what is what. A good start could be you write a tool that output what parts in a file are not yet understood.